# How to use Error handling in powershell for invoke-expression running in background?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

My code looks some what like this.

```
$OutCmd ='somecommand'
$job = start-job -ScriptBlock { Param([string]$InnerSB)
    Invoke-Expression $InnerSB
} -ArgumentList $OutCmd
```

I want to catch job output if my $outCmd runs successfully or catch the full error message if $outCmd fails. I also want to know if command is failed or not.

$job.state is not helpful, it is showing as completed even when the command is failed.

Comment: What about using a `try` `catch` block inside `$InnerSB` ?

Comment: `try{}catch{}` is not working. here is my simple try.
`try{$ret=Invoke-expression $cmd}
catch{$e= "failed"}
throw $e` 
Interestingly this worked outside start-job (without throw) but inside start-job it is not throwing the `$e`

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee that this will work for all cases, but typically I use something like this:

```
function Invoke-Expression-And-Check{
    param (
        [string]$Expression
    )
        $er = (invoke-expression $Expression) 2>&1
        if($er.Exception){
            throw $er.Exception
        }
}
```

The 2>&1 redirects error output to standard, which allows you to capture the $er object, which is of type ErrorRecord. If it isn't an error record it won't have an Exception field.

Once you have the error, you can catch it in a try catch, or just have your program halt.